# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.25.dylib

Tags: applescript, dyld

I used to use an AppleScript from years, but since a few days, I cannot run it anymore

I have the error message

"dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.25.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/php
  Reason: image not found"
"dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.25.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/php
  Reason: image not found (1005)"
Any idea how I can fix that

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had same problem with PHP after updated the OS X system and solved by this (type this in terminal console):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.30.dylib /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.25.dylib
```

Hope this helps you as well.

Comment: I can't due that due to running El Capitan with Rootless mode (can't change anything in /usr/lib) – is there an alternative?

Comment: Thanks! Super quick solution :)